# Node Async forEach - How to iterate by keys instead of values

Tags: node.js, node-async

I currently have the following example object:

```
"fruit" : [ { "bananas" : 2, "tomatoes" : 3 } ];
```

Let's say I'm iterating through it with the following code:

```
console.log(fruit);

async.forEach(fruit, function(item, callback) {
    console.log(item);
    callback();
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("Iterating done.");
    }
);
```

My output is the following:

```
{ 'bananas': 2, 'tomatoes': 3 }
2
3
Iterating done.
```

The separate console.log gives me the information I need, however async.forEach gives me only the values. Is it possible to have async.forEach output the keys of the object instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over `Object.keys(fruit)` instead of `fruit`:

```
async.forEach(
    Object.keys(fruit),
    function(item, callback) {
        console.log(item);
        callback();
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log("Iterating done.");
    }
);
```

Comment: Ah, I literally read about Object.keys yesterday, and I didn't realise I should use it. Works like a charm with your suggestion, thanks a lot :)